# Asus rt-n66u blocking Direct Access VPN from work Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

my Asus rt-n66u is suddenly blocking Direct Access VPN from my work. It just stopped working. I have used it for over a year. I wiped the router and no luck. I installed tomato and it' still not working. If i plug direct into my ISP modem it will connect to Direct Access. If I use another router it works. Any ideas what to do? My guess is my company changes something and its conflicting now.

LOgs if it helps. Log is saying ignoring my work domain.

```
        Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:04.1: irq 6, io mem 0x18004000
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:04.1: USB 0.0 started, EHCI 1.00
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.debug kernel: vlan1: add 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.debug kernel: vlan1: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: vlan1: dev_set_allmulti(master, 1)
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: vlan1: dev_set_promiscuity(master, 1)
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: device vlan1 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: usb 1-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: scsi0 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: device eth2 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: br0: port 3(eth2) entering forwarding state
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: br0: port 2(eth1) entering forwarding state
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: br0: port 1(vlan1) entering forwarding state
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.warn kernel: vlan2: Setting MAC address to  30 85 a9 6b ee 81.
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 33:33:00:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.debug hotplug[476]: Attached USB device 1-1.4:1.0 [INTERFACE=8/6/80 PRODUCT=58f/6366/100]
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.debug kernel: vlan2: add 01:00:5e:00:00:01 mcast address to master interface
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: IMQ starting with 2 devices...
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel: IMQ driver loaded successfully.
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel:   Hooking IMQ after NAT on PREROUTING.
Dec 31 18:00:08 Coleman user.info kernel:   Hooking IMQ before NAT on POSTROUTING.
Dec 31 18:00:09 Coleman authpriv.warn dropbear[553]: Failed loading /etc/dropbear/dropbear_ecdsa_host_key
Dec 31 18:00:09 Coleman authpriv.info dropbear[556]: Running in background
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: started, version 2.72+ cachesize 1500
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth DNSSEC loop-detect
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCP, IP range 1.1.100.200 -- 1.1.100.252, lease time 7d
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.warn dnsmasq[567]: failed to access /etc/resolv.dnsmasq: No such file or directory
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman user.info init[1]: NGinX - daemon not enabled cancelled generation of config file
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman user.debug init[1]: starting rstats.
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman user.notice kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multi    Flash Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman user.notice kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Dec 31 18:00:10 Coleman user.debug init[1]: starting cstats.
Dec 31 18:00:11 Coleman user.notice root: Transmission daemon successfully stoped
Dec 31 18:00:11 Coleman user.notice root: MySQL successfully stoped
Dec 31 18:00:11 Coleman user.notice root: Stoping NFS Server ...
Dec 31 18:00:11 Coleman user.notice root: NFS Server stoped ...
Dec 31 18:00:11 Coleman user.info init[1]: Asus RT-N66U: Tomato 1.28.0000 MIPSR2-130 K26 USB AIO-64K
Dec 31 18:00:18 Coleman daemon.err apcupsd[414]: apcupsd FATAL ERROR in linux-usb.c at line 609 Cannot find UPS device -- For a link to detailed USB trouble shooting information, please see <http://www.apcupsd.com/support.html>.
Dec 31 18:00:18 Coleman daemon.err apcupsd[414]: apcupsd error shutdown completed
Dec 31 18:00:27 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.248 c4:43:8f:f5:68:57 
Dec 31 18:00:27 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.248 c4:43:8f:f5:68:57 android-46900eb2661ed655
Dec 31 18:00:29 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.209 10:ae:60:a4:c6:0a 
Dec 31 18:00:29 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.209 10:ae:60:a4:c6:0a kindle-c18613eca
Dec 31 18:00:29 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.243 80:86:f2:bc:ac:d2 
Dec 31 18:00:29 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.243 80:86:f2:bc:ac:d2 StephLappy
Dec 31 18:00:35 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.223 c4:17:fe:63:03:31 
Dec 31 18:00:35 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[567]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.223 c4:17:fe:63:03:31 M6400
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman user.debug dhcpc-event[767]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: using nameserver 192.168.44.1#53
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman user.debug init[1]: 182: pptp peerdns disabled
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[567]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: started, version 2.72+ cachesize 1500
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth DNSSEC loop-detect
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: asynchronous logging enabled, queue limit is 5 messages
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCP, IP range 1.1.100.200 -- 1.1.100.252, lease time 7d
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: reading /etc/resolv.dnsmasq
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: using nameserver 192.168.44.1#53
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq[770]: read /etc/dnsmasq/hosts/hosts - 3 addresses
Dec 31 18:00:45 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: read /etc/dnsmasq/dhcp/dhcp-hosts
Jun 20 23:06:23 Coleman cron.err crond[575]: time disparity of 23914326 minutes detected
Jun 20 23:07:40 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.217 b4:b6:76:35:cc:b2 
Jun 20 23:07:40 Coleman daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: Ignoring domain MYWORKDOMAIN.CORP.NET for DHCP host name COLEMAST4
Jun 20 23:07:40 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.217 b4:b6:76:35:cc:b2 COLEMAST4
Jun 20 23:07:43 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.217 b4:b6:76:35:cc:b2 
Jun 20 23:07:43 Coleman daemon.warn dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: Ignoring domain MYWORKDOMAIN.CORP.NET for DHCP host name COLEMAST4
Jun 20 23:07:43 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.217 b4:b6:76:35:cc:b2 COLEMAST4
Jun 20 23:10:26 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 60:45:bd:a8:31:12 
Jun 20 23:10:26 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 1.1.100.229 60:45:bd:a8:31:12 
Jun 20 23:10:26 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 60:45:bd:a8:31:12 
Jun 20 23:10:26 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 1.1.100.229 60:45:bd:a8:31:12 
Jun 20 23:10:26 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.229 60:45:bd:a8:31:12 
Jun 20 23:10:26 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.229 60:45:bd:a8:31:12 
Jun 20 23:18:09 Coleman daemon.notice miniupnpd[1487]: version 1.9 started
Jun 20 23:18:09 Coleman daemon.notice miniupnpd[1487]: Listening for NAT-PMP/PCP traffic on port 5351
Jun 20 23:20:59 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.243 80:86:f2:bc:ac:d2 
Jun 20 23:20:59 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.243 80:86:f2:bc:ac:d2 StephLappy
Jun 20 23:29:20 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.1.12 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 
Jun 20 23:29:20 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPNAK(br0) 192.168.1.12 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 wrong network
Jun 20 23:29:23 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 
Jun 20 23:29:23 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 1.1.100.233 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 
Jun 20 23:29:24 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.233 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 
Jun 20 23:29:24 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.233 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 Sarahs-iPhone
Jun 20 23:29:28 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 1.1.100.233 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 
Jun 20 23:29:28 Coleman daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[770]: DHCPACK(br0) 1.1.100.233 84:8e:0c:3d:31:81 Sarahs-iPhone
```